# Parse an HTML fragment whitelisting some custom tags

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an HTML fragment that contains a custom HTML tag using Nokogiri.

Example:

```
string = "<div>hello</div>\n<custom-tag></custom-tag>"
```

I tried to load it in many ways, but none is optimal.

If I use Nokogiri::HTML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(string)
```

When I use `to_html`, it adds a `doctype` and an `html` tag that wraps the content. It's undesired.

If I use Nokogiri::XML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(string)
```

I got `Error at line 2: Extra content at the end of the document`, since in XML there must be a root tag that wraps all the document content. If I try to save this content again, The output is `<div>hello</div>` (every tag after the first is removed)

I tried also `doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment`:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(string)
```

But it complains about the `custom-tag`.

How can I make Nokogiri parse correctly with this HTML fragment?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: @AmitSharma I expect to parse the string with no errors in HTML, even if it contains a `custom-tag`. I need to make a few xpath queries, edit the content, and serialize back to html without errors.

Comment: Have you tried this `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(string).inner_html` ?

Comment: @RORDeveloper Try to check `doc.errors`. Should I just ignore them? How can I be sure that the content will be intact?
@AmitSharma `inner_html` seems to work the same as `to_html`...

Comment: @ProGM `inner_html` does not  adds a `doctype` but it wraps the content  with `html`

Comment: @AmitSharma ... yes, but I don't want the `html` tag as well. This is not my request. I want to parse the content and save it back without any change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(string)` is the way to go, you can ignore `doc.errors` complaining about the invalid tag.

You *are* giving it invalid HTML, so you can't expect it to not report errors, but HTML parsers tend to be forgiving.

You can also use `Nokogiri::XML.fragment`, if you're sure the rest of it is well-formed. That won't give you errors about undefined tags.

Comment: HTML parsers in browsers aren't forgiving, they just try to be helpful and will rewrite the HTML until it's syntactically correct, even if it's not what the original intent was. Nokogiri will also do some fixup. Knowing that `doc.errors` says there are problems is important because tags can move during fixup. Allowing Nokogiri to parse the content as an XML fragment is probably the easiest since XML is more accepting of unknown tags, but it still has a rigid syntax that HTML doesn't so it might not solve all the problems.